# AppWidgetHost createView on main thread

Tags: android, android-appwidget

When setting up a widget I have to call the `createView()` method from the main thread, else the widgets will say 'Couln't load widget' and take the error-view.

But when the user has many widgets installed, it can take up to a few seconds to load my launcher. (max 300ms each).

Is there a way to create the `AppWidgetHostView` off the main thread?

Part of code:

```
AppWidgetHost lWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(lContext, HOST_ID);

mWidgetId = lWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();

AppWidgetManager.getInstance(lContext).bindAppWidgetId(mWidgetId, info.provider);

new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AppWidgetHostView lHostView = lWidgetHost.createView(lContext, mWidgetId, info);

        addView(lHostView);
        lWidgetHost.startListening();
    }
}
```

Ps. Yes, my launcher is a system-app and has the correct permission to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did when I needed to create widgets in an async task  launched from a listview's getview:

```
public class CustomHostView extends AppWidgetHostView {
boolean errorFlag = false;
@Override
protected View getErrorView() {
    errorFlag = true;
    return super.getErrorView();

}
```

then after you call createview from a different thread you know if there was an error and you need to call it again from the main thread. In my experience about 10-20% of widgets require the main thread.

Also, I don't know what type of home screen you're making, but make sure you're not creating many more widgets than can be seen on screen at once + the page to the left or right, for example.